# White lines between heatmap cells when zooming in (browser zoom)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I have the following problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahfd1ejz/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    style: {
        fontFamily: '"Roboto", sans-serif'
    },
    animation: false,
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },...
```

Without zooming in the browser it looks nice:

[image: No zooming]

When I zoom in (browser zoom, Chrome):

[image]

**Does anybody know why these white lines appear?**

A workaround would be to increase the rowSize /colSize so that they overlap, but that's not nice...

Comment: That's weird because in my Chrome everything's working fine. Could you tell me what version of the browser and OS are you using?

Comment: In firefox there are white lines even without zooming...

Comment: Version of Chrome is: Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is reported on Highcharts GitHub repository here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6783

In short, it's caused by `shape-rendering` property which default is set to `geometricPrecission`. To workaround it, you just need to set this parameter value to `optimizeSpeed` on every element with `.highcharts-point` class, like below:

```
.highcharts-point {
  shape-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}
```

**Live example:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WgKwOe

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I was looking for :)